# How to group array and display it in a dropdown in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to group values in an array in caekphp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597240/how-to-group-values-in-an-array-in-caekphp)

I have two array, team leads array and team members array.
Under each team lead there will be few team members.
i used to fetch the teammembers with the correspoding team lead id only.
I need to group them and display it as a **single dropdown** where under each team lead the corresponding team members should be displayed.

> TeamLead1
>       TeamMember1
>       TeamMember2
>       TeamMember3
>       TeamMember4
>     TeamLead2
>       TeamMember1
>       TeamMember2
>       TeamMember3
>       TeamMember4

i know that we need to use foreach loop, but i got confused and lost.
Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.